# How to efficiently load object properties with values from a datatable

Tags: vb.net, object, dataset

I have created a function which queries a table and takes the results and populates a collection of objects, matching column name to property.

It is too slow and I need to optimize it. Is there a different technique for doing the same thing which is faster? It seems to be the CallByName is the primary slow-down.

I am pretty sure I can speed this up by using early binding and making a function tailored to each object type, but that is not a desirable outcome.

Thanks,
Brad

```
Public Function GetRecords(Sql As String, ConnStr As String, ObjType As Object) As List(Of Object)

    Dim objList As New List(Of Object)()
    Dim SingleObj As Object
    Dim ColumnName As String

    Dim dt As DataTable = ReturnTableQuery(Sql, ConnStr)

    If dt Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        SingleObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(ObjType.ToString))
        For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            ColumnName = col.ColumnName
            If row(ColumnName).ToString <> "" Then
                Try
                    CallByName(SingleObj, ColumnName, CallType.Set, row(ColumnName))
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
            End If
        Next
        objList.Add(SingleObj)
    Next

    Return objList

End Function
```

Comment: Define "too slow".  How many records are you working with, how long does it take and how long do you think is acceptable?

Comment: It was taking a few seconds to process 25 records with about 20 columns. But there was something screwy with my computer. After a reboot, it sped up to a more than acceptable speed. Don't know what was up but I guess I am happy now.